# StepLDA without Cross Validation

Tags: r, lda, r-caret

I would like to select the variables on the basis of the training error. 
For that reason I set method in trainControl to "none". However, if I run the function below twice I get two different errors (correctness rates). 
In this exsample the difference is not worth to mention. Even so I wouldn't have expected any difference at all.

Does somebody know where this difference comes from?

```
library(caret)

c_1 <- trainControl(method = "none")

maxvar     <-(4) 
direction <-"forward"
tune_1     <-data.frame(maxvar,direction)

train(Species~., data=iris, method = "stepLDA", trControl=c_1, tuneGrid=tune_1)->tr
```

1st

```
`stepwise classification', using 10-fold cross-validated correctness rate of method lda'.
150 observations of 4 variables in 3 classes; direction: forward
stop criterion: assemble 4 best variables.
correctness rate: 0.96;  in: "Petal.Width";  variables (1): Petal.Width 
correctness rate: 0.96667;  in: "Sepal.Width";  variables (2): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width 
correctness rate: 0.97333;  in: "Petal.Length";  variables (3): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length 
correctness rate: 0.98;  in: "Sepal.Length";  variables (4): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length 

 hr.elapsed min.elapsed sec.elapsed 
       0.00        0.00        0.28
```

2nd

```
> train(Species~., data=iris, method = "stepLDA", trControl=c_1, tuneGrid=tune_1)->tr
 `stepwise classification', using 10-fold cross-validated correctness rate of method lda'.
150 observations of 4 variables in 3 classes; direction: forward
stop criterion: assemble 4 best variables.
correctness rate: 0.96;  in: "Petal.Width";  variables (1): Petal.Width 
correctness rate: 0.96;  in: "Sepal.Width";  variables (2): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width 
correctness rate: 0.96667;  in: "Petal.Length";  variables (3): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length 
correctness rate: 0.98;  in: "Sepal.Length";  variables (4): Petal.Width, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length 

 hr.elapsed min.elapsed sec.elapsed 
        0.0         0.0         0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are still doing 10-fold cross validation. As long as you do not set the seed you will always get a slightly different answer when you train the model multiple times.

if you run this piece of code, including the set.seed you will get the same correctness rates.

```
set.seed(42)
tr <- train(Species~., data=iris, method = "stepLDA", trControl=c_1, tuneGrid=tune_1)
```

#### Edit based on comment:

The 10-fold cross-validated correctness rate is not coming from Caret, but from the stepclass function from the klaR package.

> stepclass(x, grouping, method, improvement = 0.05, maxvar = Inf, 
>       start.vars = NULL, direction = c("both", "forward", "backward"), 
>       criterion = "CR",  **fold = 10**, cv.groups = NULL, output = TRUE, 
>       min1var = TRUE, ...)
>
> fold   parameter for cross-validation; omitted if ‘cv.groups’ is
>   specified.

you can adjust this if you want to by just adding the fold parameter to the train function:

`tr <- train(Species~., data=iris, method = "stepLDA", trControl=c_1, tuneGrid=tune_1, fold = 1)`

But a fold of 1 is meaningless. you will get a bunch of warnings and errors.

Comment: The line in the output saying "using 10 fold CV..." never changes (even if I choose k = 5).  I think it is sth. else.

Comment: Thank you! I expected something like that. Your answer helps me to understand how the caret package works. So I can not only set the tuning parameters but also all other parameters of the original functions?

If I understand correctly, then telling stepLDA via trainControl to perform CV causes a cross validation of already cross validated results. Is that true?

Comment: That is true. Just run the code with method = cv and you get the cv from caret with the cross-validated correctness rate.