# Stepwise Linear Discriminant Analysis in R

Tags: r, feature-selection, caret

I'm trying to do feature selection on a set of 1250 features and 94 obs.
The `caret` package is supposed to perform stepwiseLDA for feature selection.
I tried running  `tr <- train(Class~., data=data, method = "stepLDA")`, and I obtained several output messages like the one below:

```
> tr <- train(Class~., data=data, method = "stepLDA")
 `stepwise classification', using 10-fold cross-validated correctness rate of method lda'.
94 observations of 1250 variables in 2 classes; direction: both
stop criterion: improvement less than 5%.
correctness rate: 0.78556;  in: "CPP1H.Alpha._RP";  variables (1): CPP1H.Alpha._RP 
correctness rate: 0.84444;  in: "CP5.Beta.2._RP";  variables (2): CPP1H.Alpha._RP, CP5.Beta.2._RP 
correctness rate: 0.89556;  in: "C5.Theta._CV";  variables (3): CPP1H.Alpha._RP, CP5.Beta.2._RP, C5.Theta._CV 

 hr.elapsed min.elapsed sec.elapsed 
       0.00        0.00       52.98
```

I don't understand if it is selecting only 3 variables out of 1250 giving me a correctness rate of 89.56%.
Is there a way to obtain a list of the set of selected features?

I can't find any other information online, and I doubt that my approach is correct.

***EDIT***

As suggested in the comments, find hereby the demonstration of my search of similar questions on SO and google.

The following questions on SO report the use of the *train* function in `caret` with the stepLDA parameter, but none of them explain how to interpret the output:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77414/step-wise-feature-selection-with-caret ,
[Stepwise Linear Discriminant Analysis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77269311/stepwise-linear-discriminant-analysis-in-r) , [StepLDA without Cross Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159649/steplda-without-cross-validation) .

Page 9 of this document (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/2627435.2697065) describe what the stepLDA function is actually doing, but stepclass function at page 63 of the `klaR` package documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/klaR/klaR.pdf) should be the function caret is referring to, and finally only this page ([https://pages.mtu.edu/~shanem/psy5220/daily/Day12/classification.html#split-half-and-n-fold-cross-validation](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshanem/psy5220/daily/Day12/classification.html#split-half-and-n-fold-cross-validation)) gives a complete example of the stepclass function in `klaR`.

Nonetheless, scientific papers report the use of both functions for feature selection (http://hdl.handle.net/2115/73369 or https://pub.epsilon.slu.se/30677/1/axelsson-c-r-et-al-20230414.pdf), but there is no script available.

Comment: Have you done any search for examples of how to process such model results? What was your search strategy and what were the sources you considered for searching?  I suspect the lack of responses comes from the lack of a [MCVE].

Comment: @IRTFM I mainly searched on `caret` official documentation but I did not found any example, the documentation only reports the parameters to be used with the ` train`  function.